Can't install Eclipse on Windows 10
I have java 23 installed, I download the eclipse installer, but it does not start and gives this log:
`!SESSION 2024-11-08 13:24:02.001 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.33.0.20240905-0613
java.version=21.0.4
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-11-08 13:24:04.027
!MESSAGE Activated before the state location was initialized. Retry after the state location is     initialized.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-11-08 13:24:04.643
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\800\0\.cp\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path:     C:\eclipse;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\WireGuard\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin;C:\Users\1\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;.
    no swt in java.library.path:     C:\eclipse;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\WireGuard\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-23\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\bin;C:\Users\1\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;.
    C:\Users\1\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура
    Can't load library: C:\Users\1\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\1\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll
    C:\Users\1\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.STARTUPINFO.<clinit>(STARTUPINFO.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)

`
I deleted it, reinstalled it several times, specified the path in Environment Variables, I don’t know what to fix?
I tried downloading via zip file, checked the path in environment variables, deleted and reinstalled several times. I don't know what the problem could be.
Update #2
I delete java and I launched the installer and now it shows the following log:
`!SESSION 2024-11-11 19:20:49.608 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.12
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-11-11 19:20:52.272
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer (158).
!STACK 0 `

Update #3
I download zip file from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ (first link for Windows)
I unpacked the zip file into an empty folder and when I launched it I got the following log:
!SESSION 2024-11-11 20:54:17.750 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.33.0.20240905-0613
java.version=21.0.4
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-11-11 20:54:19.716
!MESSAGE Activated before the state location was initialized. 
Retry after the state location is initialized.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-11-11 20:54:20.401
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
...


Maybe this

You could try to download the zip file you want manually and extract and run it without using the installer.

C:\Users\1\ looks odd. Can you confirm that this is your correct home directory? Please add more details about your Windows version.

I have java 23 installed but eclipse is not using it: java.version=21.0.4. Is your Windows installation 32 bits or 64 bits? Are your JDKs (both versions) 32 bits or 64 bits?

@aled Eclipse comes with a built-in Java 21 which it uses to run, that is 64 bit

@dan1st I tried the zip file, it didn't help.

@aled My Windows 10 (64 bits). I have installed eclipse early and want update, so I delete it and install again and then these problems appeared.
I install java 21.0.4 (64-bit) (and specified the path in Environment Variables), but have same problem

I think that Eclipse ignores JAVA_HOME by default. And as @greg-449 mentioned it has its own JDK 21.0.4 embedded, so there is no need to use another one.

@howlger My Windows 10 (64 bits)

@aled I delete java and I launched the installer and now it shows the following log (I update the question (Update #2))

eclipse.buildId=unknown in your log contradicts what you say. Please describe exactly what you have downloaded (share the link) and what you have installed so that it can be reproduced. Please improve your question instead of adding comments. Just use a ZIP file, unzip it in an empty folder. You do not need install Java on your system or set any environment variables. Just double-click the eclipse.exe file and choose a fresh workspace (an empty or not yet existing directory). If it does not work, please show your log file.
